# What is the status of Stack Overflow Cities?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

There used to be a section in Stack Overflow Careers called "Cities." But it seems to have disappeared with the merge into the regular stackoverflow.com website. I enjoyed browsing it to discover other tech hubs (some of which I had no idea were tech hubs) and enjoyed the images and descriptions. I also liked the job salary averages it listed - I don't know how they were computed, but it seemed more realistic than other sites I browsed. Anyway, it was a nice area to get a "flavor" of each hub.

Will the cities portal come back?

Comment: The same as GeoCities.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right now, no, cities is not making a return. Why? Well, mostly because each city required a fair amount of work from our marketing team and then a small amount of code from the dev team. Essentially the process didn't scale.

We *do* have plans to introduce something that replaces city pages, but focused more around job search. This is still in the early stages of planning so any ideas on what you'd like to see are welcome!